# Mismatch alignment tab character &

Tags: macros

The error bar also shows me you cannot use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode....&analysis. I cant figure out where this issue is coming from. Initially everything was fine, but when I added a bibliography that contains some characters which I think was not allowed I stated having this issue. I removed the BibTeX but the error still remains.

```
    %appendixprefix sorgt dafuer, dass "Anhang" vor jedem Anhang steht
    %openany sorgt dafuer, dass ein Kapitel auf jeder Seite beginnen kann
    %        nicht nur rechts
    %bibtotoc sorgt dafuer, dass das Literaturverzeichnis automatisch im
    %Inhaltsverzeichnis erscheint
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,parskip=half,final,appendixprefix,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
    % uncomment the following line (mutual exclusive to the one above) to enter the draft mode.
    %\documentclass[colordvi,%11pt,a4paper,halfparskip,draft,headings,appendixprefix,bibtotoc]%{scrbook}
    %Line space
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing

    % german language support (hyphenation etc)  
    %\usepackage{british}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    % if you have compilation problems, make sure the files are actually encoded as UTF-8
    % if utf8 fails, use latin1 instead and encode your files as ISO 8859-1
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    % provides the \url{} command to pretty print urls
    \usepackage{url}

    % needed for a german bibliography-style (s. below)
    %\usepackage{bibgerm}

    % allows to \includegraphics
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    % allows tables to break over pages.
    \usepackage{supertabular}

    % allows to specify absolute texpos for textboxes. This is generally only important for the titlepage
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

    % Package for sourcecode
    \usepackage{listings}

    % Packages for better tables
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \usepackage[pdftex,
                 %plainpages={false},
                 bookmarksnumbered={true},
                 pdfstartview={FitBH}]{hyperref}

    % some configuration for the amount of text on a single page
    \usepackage{typearea}
    \areaset[1.5cm]{418pt}{658pt}
    \setlength{\headheight}{37pt}

    % To avoid nasty mistakes like having comments directly in the textflow
    % the following \todo macro was defined. With that you can enter
    % \todo{What I still have to do here} 
    % inside of your text and a marker will appear at the page's margin with the 
    % text "What I still have to do here".
    % The first line activates this feature. If you comment it out and uncomment
    % the second line below there will be no error messages and no todos will be shown
    % anymore. So - even if you have forgotten to delete one of them - they will not appear
    % in the final printout. 
    \newcommand{\todo}[1]{\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{TODO:} #1}}
    %\newcommand{\todo}[1]{}

    \begin{document}
    % the next two lines influence the detailedness of the table of contents
    % and to what structure depth numbers are written before sections/subsections/paragraphs
    % You should not touch this
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \frontmatter
    % here the titlepage is included. Look into the file "titelseite.tex" to 
    % adapt it to your needs (name, title etc.)

    \input{frontpage}
    \include{content/abstract}
    \include{Eidesstattliche_Erklaerung}

    \tableofcontents

    % list(s) of figures, tables and listings are optional
    %\listoffigures

    \mainmatter

    % To assemble the whole document
    % Please be aware that each file will begin on a new page
    % therefore chapters should be put into such a file.
    % There cannot be an include statement inside of an "included" file.
    % So if you want to further divide your document - use \input inside of 
    % the included files. \input will not begin on a new page.
    \include{content/chapter1}
    \include{content/chapter2}
    \include{content/chapter3}
    \include{content/chapter4}
    \include{content/chapter5}
    \include{content/chapter6}

    % Appendix chapters to be put here. They should be enumerated with capital letters.
    \begin{appendix}
    %\include{appendix_chapterA}
    \end{appendix}

    %Bibliography
    % use alphadin for numerical labels
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

    % to finally announce where your bibliography is stored use
    \bibliography{bib/references}
    % it is also possible to have several files separated by comma. 
    %Bibliographie Angaben mit \bibliography{}

    \end{document}

%appendixprefix sorgt dafuer, dass "Anhang" vor jedem Anhang steht %openany sorgt dafuer, dass ein Kapitel auf jeder Seite beginnen kann % nicht nur rechts %bibtotoc sorgt dafuer, dass das Literaturverzeichnis automatisch im %Inhaltsverzeichnis erscheint \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,parskip=half,final,appendixprefix,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook} % uncomment the following line (mutual exclusive to the one above) to enter the draft mode. %\documentclass[colordvi,%11pt,a4paper,halfparskip,draft,headings,appendixprefix,bibtotoc]%{scrbook} %Line space \usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing

% german language support (hyphenation etc)
%\usepackage{british} \usepackage[english]{babel}

% if you have compilation problems, make sure the files are actually encoded as UTF-8 % if utf8 fails, use latin1 instead and encode your files as ISO 8859-1 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% provides the \url{} command to pretty print urls \usepackage{url}

% needed for a german bibliography-style (s. below) %\usepackage{bibgerm}

% allows to \includegraphics \usepackage{graphicx}

% allows tables to break over pages. \usepackage{supertabular}

% allows to specify absolute texpos for textboxes. This is generally only important for the titlepage \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

% Package for sourcecode \usepackage{listings}

% Packages for better tables \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[pdftex, %plainpages={false}, bookmarksnumbered={true}, pdfstartview={FitBH}]{hyperref}

% some configuration for the amount of text on a single page \usepackage{typearea} \areaset[1.5cm]{418pt}{658pt} \setlength{\headheight}{37pt}

% To avoid nasty mistakes like having comments directly in the textflow % the following \todo macro was defined. With that you can enter % \todo{What I still have to do here} % inside of your text and a marker will appear at the page's margin with the % text "What I still have to do here". % The first line activates this feature. If you comment it out and uncomment % the second line below there will be no error messages and no todos will be shown % anymore. So - even if you have forgotten to delete one of them - they will not appear % in the final printout. \newcommand{\todo}[1]{\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{TODO:} #1}} %\newcommand{\todo}[1]{}

\begin{document} % the next two lines influence the detailedness of the table of contents % and to what structure depth numbers are written before sections/subsections/paragraphs % You should not touch this \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \frontmatter % here the titlepage is included. Look into the file "titelseite.tex" to % adapt it to your needs (name, title etc.)

\input{frontpage} \include{content/abstract} \include{Eidesstattliche_Erklaerung}

\tableofcontents

% list(s) of figures, tables and listings are optional %\listoffigures

\mainmatter

% To assemble the whole document % Please be aware that each file will begin on a new page % therefore chapters should be put into such a file. % There cannot be an include statement inside of an "included" file. % So if you want to further divide your document - use \input inside of % the included files. \input will not begin on a new page. \include{content/chapter1} \include{content/chapter2} \include{content/chapter3} \include{content/chapter4} \include{content/chapter5} \include{content/chapter6}

% Appendix chapters to be put here. They should be enumerated with capital letters. \begin{appendix} %\include{appendix_chapterA} \end{appendix}

%Bibliography % use alphadin for numerical labels \bibliographystyle{plain}

% to finally announce where your bibliography is stored use \bibliography{bib/references} % it is also possible to have several files separated by comma. %Bibliographie Angaben mit \bibliography{}

\end{document}
```

This is the portion of the code reproducing the error:

```
%\documentclass[colordvi,%11pt,a4paper,halfparskip,draft,headings,appendixprefix,bibtotoc]%{scrbook}
%Line space
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
```

Hello, The error message i recieve on my console shows that there is a text with the & character "! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. ... & Analysis of Algorithms October Lecture #" there is no such text in my documents. I added this text in my references which was removed, but this errroe doesnot go away.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a small complete code reproducing the message?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This is a small self containted document that others can use to reproduce the error message you get. Currently, the error message is not reproducible since your code loads a lot of external documents that others don't have access to.

Comment: Please also explain how this is different fro your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/520961/134144

Comment: Included files in your document are not available to us. Please make your document example minimal without including files so, that we can compile as it is.